# Including additonal values to form radio buttons

Tags: html

I have a form with 3 radio buttons. The first button works as expected, but the next two have additional values. If it is possible, how can I include the additional values when radio buttons Choice2 or Choice3 are selected?

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select Report Range:</legend>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" id ="Choice1" name="contactRange" value="lastReport"/>
      <label for="Choice1">Last report</label><br>

      <input type="radio" id="Choice2" name="contactRange" value="numOfDays"/>
      <label>Reports for the last </label>
        <select>
          <option value="1"> 1 day</option>
          <option value="2"> 2 days</option>
          <option value="3"> 3 days</option>
          <option value="4"> 4 days</option>
          <option value="5"> 5 days</option>
        </select>
      <br>

      <input type="radio" id="Choice3" name="contactRange" value="dateRange">
      <label for="Choice3">Date Range</label>
        <input type="text1" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date (oldest)">
        <input type="text2" name="endDate"   placeholder="End Date (most recent)">
    </div>

    <div>
      <br><button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I tried adding value= to each of the option and text selections without success. I also tried adding a form within a form but that got pretty ugly and also did not work.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more in detail what exactly are you trying to do?
Are you trying to say that you want to additional values to be input only when the 2nd and 3rd radio buttons are selected?

Comment: You are inconsistent with your usage of closing slashes on the `<input>` tag. Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sucess!!! (Kind of... the output is ugly but it works.)

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select Report Range:</legend>

      <input type="radio" id ="Choice1" name="contactRange" value="lastReport">
      <label for="Choice1">Last report</label><br>

      <input type="radio" id="Choice2" name="contactRange" value="numOfDays">
      <label>Reports for the last </label>
        <select name="days" id="number">
          <option value="1"> 1 day</option>
          <option value="2"> 2 days</option>
          <option value="3"> 3 days</option>
          <option value="4"> 4 days</option>
          <option value="5"> 5 days</option>
        </select>
      <br>

      <input type="radio" id="Choice3" name="contactRange" value="dateRange">
      <label for="Choice3">Date Range</label>
        <input type="text1" name="startDate" placeholder="Start Date (oldest)">
        <input type="text2" name="endDate"   placeholder="End Date (most recent)" >

    <div>
      <br><button type="submit">Submit</button><br>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

First case "Last report":
contactRange=lastReport&days=1&startDate=&endDate=

Second case "Reports for the last" 2 days:
contactRange=numOfDays&days=2&startDate=&endDate=

Third case "Date Range" 10/3/2023 4:30 AM  11/2/2023 6:30 PM:
days=1&contactRange=dateRange&startDate=10%2F3%2F2023+4%3A30+AM&endDate=11%2F2%2F2023+6%3A30+PM

The server will take the form output and parse the data for the correct "contactRange=". The rest of the data is just noise.